# node populate drop down box with data from a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, drop-down-menu

I am new to front end development and trying to teach myself a bit about it.

I am having some difficulty in understanding how to populate a drop down box with data from a file.

I am using node and javascript.  I am not using any other packages right now and don't want to use anything else yet.  I have read many articles about this and see a lot of things about Express, jquery, php, ...  But I am not ready to go there yet.  I want to keep this at node and javascript for right now.

I have a simple page that will have a select box with a list of time values.  The user will then choose one of the "times" and I will do some other processing from that.  I am able to populate the select box as follows:

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Order Book Viewer</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Caveat|Open+Sans:400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="loadQuoteTimes.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
    </header>


    <form action="/submit-time" method="post">
        <div id="timeInfo">
            <fieldset>
                <select class="timeList" name="searchTime"></select>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </form>

</body>

<footer>
</footer>


</html>
```

app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function (req, resp) {
    console.log("request method: " + req.method);
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            console.log("POST invoked: " + data);
            data = data.toString();
            data = data.split('=');
            if (data[0] === 'searchTime') {
                console.log("Time to search for: " + data[1]);
            }
        }
        );
    }

    /* I realize I need to check to see if I am doing a GET before I get into this switch... */
    switch (req.url) {
        case "/submit-form":
            break;
        case "/index.html", "/":
            console.log("HTML");
            fs.readFile("index.html", function (error, pgResp) {
                if (error) {
                    resp.writeHead(404);
                    resp.write('Contents you are looking are Not Found');
                } else {
                    resp.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
                    resp.write(pgResp);
                }
                resp.end();
            });
            break;
        case "/css/styles.css":
            console.log("CSS");
            fs.readFile("css/styles.css", function (error, pgResp) {
                if (error) {
                    resp.writeHead(404);
                    resp.write('Contents you are looking are Not Found');
                } else {
                    resp.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/css' });
                    resp.write(pgResp);
                }
                resp.end();
            });
            break;
        case "/loadQuoteTimes.js":
            console.log("loadQuoteTimes");
            fs.readFile("loadQuoteTimes.js", function (error, pgResp) {
                if (error) {
                    resp.writeHead(404);
                    resp.write('Contents you are looking are Not Found');
                } else {
                    resp.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/js' });
                    resp.write(pgResp);
                }
                resp.end();
            });
            console.log("load quote times finished");
            break;
        case "/submit-time":
            break;

        case "/index.html?productKey=ff":
            console.log("product key request");
            break;

        default:
            resp.writeHead(404);
            resp.write("Contents not found: " + req.url);
            console.log("contents not found: " + req.url);
            break;

    }

}).listen(80);

console.log('Server Started listening on 80');
```

loadQuoteTimes.js

```
var ul = document.querySelector("select.timeList");


for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

  var listItem = document.createElement("option");
  listItem.value = i;
  listItem.textContent = "09:01:00.001";

  ul.appendChild(listItem);
}
```

I can get the list to show up and also get the selected item when a choice is made by using the above code.  But, that is only for a static list.  I haven't been able to figure out how to populate the list with something other than hard-coded data.  My gut tells me I need to do something with the /.index.html is loaded but I haven't been able find that magic yet.

Can someone point me in a direction or tell me if I am completely barking up the wrong tree.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a very ugly way to do this.  Essentially, you manufacture each line of javascript to send back to the browser.  I replaced the loadQuoteTimes.js case in the switch statement with the following code:

```
       case "/loadQuoteTimes.js":
            // reference the html select item
            var hd = "var ul = document.querySelector\(\"select.timeList\"\)\;";
            resp.write(hd);
            var li;
            // currently just hard coding values to get the code to work.  Replace below loop with 
            // a collection of something read from file or database
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                li = "var listItem = document.createElement\(\"option\"\)\;" + "\n";
                resp.write(li);
                li = "listItem.value = " + i + "\;" + "\n";
                resp.write(li);
                li = "listItem.textContent = \"09:00:00.001\"\;" + "\n";
                resp.write(li);
                li = "ul.appendChild\(listItem\)\;" + "\n";
                resp.write(li);
            }
            resp.end();
            break;
```